# Kotlin : How to use if-else like condition with let block for 'null' checks

Tags: android, kotlin, null

I am replacing all the null checks with let block in my code as part of a code review process.

1.
Code example with null check:

```
if(someValue != null){//run if someValue is not null}
else {//run if someValue is null}
```

2.
Code base after using let-run block if for null check,

```
var someValue : String? = null
someValue = "SOF"

someValue?.let {safeSomeValue->
//This code block will run only if someValue is not null
}?.run {
//This code block should run only when if someValue is null, like else condition
}
```

Now problem with let-run block is that both the code blocks are running even if the someValue is not null. So i am not able to replicate behaviour of if-else condition in code example 1 to run-let condition in code example 2.

Expected behaviour is to execute either let or run code block based upon if value is null or not-null.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Source - kotlinlang.org

- ?. performs a safe call (calls a method or accesses a property if the receiver is non-null)
- ?: takes the right-hand value if the left-hand value is null (the elvis operator)

Change **?.** with **?:** will solve this issue,

Code base as following, will run either let or run block based upon the null check.

```
var someValue : String? = null
someValue = "SOF"

someValue?.also {safeSomeValue->
//This code block will run only if someValue is not null
}?:run {
//This code block will run only if someValue is null, like else condition
}
```

Comment: I think, as mentioned in the other answers, use of ?.also rather than ?.let is important as ?.let is not the same as the original code (as pointed out in the other answers)...

Comment: I'm still confused, and this is a VERY common situation.  How is the elvis operator being executed?  It looks like if someValue is null, then the entire section is skipped.  ???

Answer (score 16):

> I am replacing all the null check with let block in my code

The first question here is, why? Is this somehow more readable for you than the regular `if-else` structure? I'd be generally wary of refactoring just for refactoring's sake.

The second consideration is much more important: this conversion you're doing is not equivalent to the original code, you're actually modifying the behavior with this change. Take the following piece of code:

```
var someValue : String? = null
someValue = "SOF"

someValue?.let {safeSomeValue->
    foo(someSafeValue)
    bar(someSafeValue)
} ?: run {
    println("shouldn't happen if someValue != null")
}
```

You expect the `run` block to execute only if `someValue == null`, but that's actually not the only case when it will run. The entire `someValue?.let { ... }` expression can produce `null` values not just when `someValue` itself was `null`, but also if the block passed to `let` returned `null`. In this case, if the `bar()` function call results in `null`, the `run` statement will be executed afterwards, therefore running both branches of what you thought was a fancied up `if-else` statement.

Comment: +1: Don't refactor your code away from a solid time-tested solution to something else just because it's new and fancy or someone told you it was more idiomatic for the language. If you can't give a tangible reason for the change, then don't fix what isn't broken.

Comment: To answer your question: why?  `let` blocks are thread-safe, but if-else are not.  The compiler will not let you access `someValue` if it thinks that it's even possible to be null.  At least that's how I understand my compiler's errors.

Answer (score 16):

To give a very concrete example of what zsmb13's answer talks about:

```
val someValue = 0
someValue?.let { safeSomeValue->
    println("then")
    null
} ?: run {
    println("else")
}
```

prints both `then` and `else`. You *can* fix this by using `also` instead of `let`:

```
val someValue = 0
someValue?.also { safeSomeValue->
    println("then")
    null
} ?: run {
    println("else")
}
```

will only print `then`. It may be useful to read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html and figure out why, and to prove it's indeed always equivalent to the original `if ... else`. But I also agree with zsmb13 that it's probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 7):

You can create an extension function, like this

```
fun <T> T?.whenNull(block: () -> Unit) = this ?: block()
```

then you call it like this

```
somevalue?.let { safeSomeValue ->
    // TODO
}.whenNull {
    // execute when someValue is null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you will find the following useful

```kotlin
inline fun <T> T?.itOrNull(
    ifValue: (T) -> Unit,
    ifNull: () -> Unit
): Unit = when (this) {
    null -> ifNull()
    else -> ifValue(this)
}
```

usage:

```kotlin
data.title?.itOrNull(
   { view.text = it },
   { view.visibility = View.GONE }
)
```

Comment: Thor: I like this one

Answer (score 0):

You can write two extension functions, eg: "ifSafe" and "ifNull", that can be used individually or chained together to mimic the if/else pattern:

```
fun <T> T?.ifSafe(block: (t:T?) -> Unit) = if (this!=null) block(this) else this
fun Any?.ifNull(block: () -> Unit?) = if (this==null) block().also{return null} else this

fun main() {

    var someValue = 4
    var nullValue = null
    
    someValue.ifSafe { safeSomeValue ->
        println("someValue: "+safeSomeValue.toString())
        null
    }.ifNull{
        println("someValue is null.")
    }
    
    someValue.ifNull{
        println("someValue is null.")
    }.ifSafe{ safeSomeValue ->
        println(safeSomeValue)
    }
    
    nullValue.ifNull{
         println("nullValue is null.")
    }
    
}
```